# Combo box in Java - nullpointer

Tags: java, spring, combobox

I am trying to add this list of Strings

```
private String[] dest = {"New York", "Dahab", "Rome", "Sydney", "Tokyo"};
```

To this combo box like so

```
    for(int i = 0; i < dest.length; i++){
        System.out.println(dest[i]);
        destinationField.addItem(dest[i]);
    }
```

However I get a NullPointerException on the destinationField.addItem(dest[i]); line

```
JComboBox<String> destinationField;
```

Comment: Is `destinationField` null?

Comment: and what is destinationField?

Comment: JComboBox<String> destinationField;

Answer (score 3):

Probably your destinationField is getting there in a `null` form, because otherwise, if the problem was the `dest[i]` you would have a nullpointer in the line `System.out.println(dest[i]);`.

Try this:

```
JComboBox<String> destinationField = new JComboBox<>();
```

Your reference `destinationField` was not pointing to a real object in memory, so when you tried to use it inside the `for`, it didn't have a real object in memory. So, the `new` word makes it, allocate a real object to memory.

Comment: Worked, thank you! Can you explain what was wrong please as I dont get it.

Comment: Actually I understand, it gave null before because it was set to null?

Comment: I added an explanation on the post